# Broken UVs for Maya/Mudbox model

Tags: 3d, models, 3d-meshes, maya

I have tried using the automatic mapping in Mudbox and Maya, neither worked sufficiently, I was still experiencing polygon overlap. I tried mapping separate limbs but I came to the same problem, this is the very first model I made and as a result i didn't know to make the limbs separate layers / faces.
[image: What im starting with]

[image: This is what im looking to do but my model is at 800,000 polys]

[image: This is what i currently have, UV's why]

[image: This is what maya is displaying as the current automatic UV Riging]

Comment: You need to better describe the problem. So far you only hint at it "Broken UVs" and "polygon overlap". But you're rather vague about it too "neither worked sufficiently" (What does that mean?) "but I came to the same problem" (What problem exactly?). This isn't a forum for back and forth discussion. You need to post your entire question with all the supporting information up-front. Tell us what you want, what you've tried to do to get there and what you have now.

Comment: I think "polygon overlap" means there were multiple polygons in the texture coordinates that were sharing space on the texture. so what he wants to know is if there's an automatic mapping that will result in each polygon getting it's own unique space in the texture.

Comment: yeah, thats what i was trying to say, sorry im new to this.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of what you have and a image of what you're expecting (or something similar to it), would help?